# If cell value is #NV get another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code to work with

```
    Set sourcerange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AW2:AW" & lastRow)
    Set resultrange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:H" & lastRow)

    i = 1


    For Each cell In sourcerange
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 5).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 7).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & cell.row).Value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 8).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & cell.row).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
Next cell
```

Now to my problem:
Sometimes it happens, that the value from this code:

```
resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X" & cell.row).Value
```

is #NV. In this case, I want to copy the value from the column "AA". But I've got no idea how to accomplish this. Is there a way to add something in my code to bring it to work? Or do I have to rewrite everything?

Comment: what language settings are you running that you are getting `#NV` instead of `#NA` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to try this:

```
Dim cell As Range

Set SourceRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AW2:AW" & lastRow)
Set ResultRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:H" & lastRow)

i = 1

strng = "O X P J K G H I" '<-- list the columns index you want to grab data from, in order
With ResultRange
    For Each cell In SourceRange
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 8).FormulaR1C1 = Split("=Sheet1!" & Replace(strng, " ", cell.Row & " =Sheet1!") & cell.Row)
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 8).Value
            If .Cells(i, 2) = "#NV" Then .Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & cell.Row).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    .Value = .Value
End With
```